# Sending a fixed-length header

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm trying to send data with a fixed-length header that tells the server how many bytes of data it's going to have to have available to read before it reads it. I'm having trouble doing this, though. The maximum number of bytes of data I want to be able to send at once is 65536, so I'm sending a `uint16_t` type variable as the header of my data because the maximum number it can represent is 65536.

The problem is, a `uint16_t` takes up two bytes, but numbers less than 255 only require one byte. So I have this code on the client side:

```
uint16_t messageSize = clientSendBuf.size(); //clientSendBuf is the data I want to send
char *bytes((char*)&messageSize);
clientSendBuf.prepend(bytes);
client.write(clientSendBuf);
```

And on the server, I handle receiving messages like this:

```
char serverReceiveBuf[65536];
uint16_t messageSize;
client->read((char*)&messageSize, sizeof(uint16_t));
client->read(serverReceiveBuf, messageSize);
```

I'm going to change this around a bit later because it's not the best solution (particularly for when all of the data isn't available yet), but I want to get this fixed first. My problem is that when `clientSendBuf.size()` is too small (in my test case it was 16 bytes, I assume this happens for every value under 255) reading data with

```
client->read((char*)&messageSize, sizeof(uint16_t));
```

reads a second byte that isn't part of the header, giving and incorrect value for `messageSize` and crashing the server. If I replace `sizeof(uint16_t)` with `1`, then the server reads the data fine as I'd expect, although then I have a `messageSize` maximum of 255, which is much lower than I want. How do I make it so that the `messageSize` prepended to `clientSendBuf` is always two bytes, even for numbers <255?

Comment: Why wouldn't the header *still* be 16 bits (two bytes) even when the sending buffer size is small? Even if you only have one single byte of data to send, then you should *still* send the two-byte fixed header.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You tell me. I thought so too, but when I send a small `messageSize` (and check with debugging) the value of `messageSize` on the server side is not the same as the `messageSize` sent by the client. Additionally, the data in `serverReceiveBuf` does not match the data sent, it's off by one byte (and the first byte is what I expect the second byte to be). When I change `sizeof(uint16_t)` with `1`, everything is fine but I'm then limited to 255 bytes which is not good enough. My question is how do I ensure that the header is **always** two bytes, even when `messageSize` needs one

Comment: Also consider [endianess issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), that can occur when you exchange numeric data between client and server this way. I'd recommend converting the `uint16_t` values to network byte order (i.e. big endian) consistently.

Comment: Then you need to see first what the `prepend` function does, do it only add *one* byte? I'm suspicious of it because it don't take a number of bytes to add. Following that, you might want to see what the `write` function does.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It prepends however many bytes the data requires. So when I use `char *bytes((char*)&messageSize);` and `messageSize` is <255, `*bytes` only requires one byte to store and that's all that will be prepended. How else can I send a fixed-length header?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I know that as well, I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible right now to isolate the problem.

Comment: Then the header is no longer fixed length! It's of variable length depending on the size of the data. *Always* add the full two-byte header.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ...I know. I've made it very clear that I'm aware that the header isn't fixed length and that I want it to be fixed length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
 clientSendBuf.prepend(bytes);
```

Should also be told that it needs to send 2 bytes; now it [treats the `bytes` as a zero-terminated string](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qbytearray.html#prepend-2), which accidently works since on your platform the second byte of 0x0010 is zero (using little-endian numbers: 0x16, 0x00).

The [`prepend(char*, int)` method](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qbytearray.html#prepend-3) will do the trick:

```
// use this instead:
cliendSendBuf.prepend(bytes, sizeof(messageSize));
```

Comment: I understand that but my question is **how** do I make `prepend()` **always** prepend two bytes, even when `*bytes` only requires one byte? Or rather, how else can I send a fixed-length header?